# Access denied in a web service windows and anonymous with Impersonation

Tags: wcf, authentication, iis, .net-4.5

First of all this issue has been happening on .Net framework 4.5 only.

I have been dealing with this issue of not connecting to a 3rd party web service
The third party web service is one of Hyland's Unity API. This is the problem our users have been complaining. 
We have been experiencing 'Access denied' when we try to connect to their webservice Unity API. The stack trace says 'Security Access Denied'. We use domain authentication to connect. We are set up use Windows authentication and anonymous in IIS.All this is fine.

Once the administrator account, meaning person who has administrator privileges makes a successful connection, it works fine for the rest of the users.  This administrator and everyone else is set up to use Domain authentication except that one is admin and the other is not. Still if the admin makes the first call, then all is well. 
Let’s say the first person to login is not an administrator the connection to OnBase fails and fails for everyone including a person who is set up as Administrator. At this point they have to do a IIS reset on the server and make an administrator login first to set things right.

I did some research on this. Why use anonymous authentication? So I decided to turn off anonymous in   IIS and some webconfig settings to deny and allow. 
I am getting this problem about client scheme Negotiate and that the header is excepting something else. So I went about using

```
<authenticationmode = "Windows" /> 
<deny users> *?
```

This did not help. I didnt know where this Negotiate is coming in. So followed it all the way and came across this call in the service. callerWindowsIdentity has authentication Type='Negotiate'. What does this Impersonate() actually do? Does it use IUSR account or app pool identity?

```
  [OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]

 public string GetSessionDomainAuthentication()
        {
            var result = string.Empty;

            var callerWindowsIdentity = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity;
            if (callerWindowsIdentity != null)
            {
                using (callerWindowsIdentity.Impersonate())
                {
                    // Access a file as the caller.
                    var myapp = Application.Connect(Environment.UserName)

                    if (myapp != null)
                    {
                        result = myapp.SessionID;
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

So could Impersonation be the problem. I was reading that if impersonation enabled always impersonates the access token that IIS provides to ISAPI extensions. That token can be a previously authenticated user.
Could this be the reason why a first time admin logs in and then its good for everyone.   Does impersonation reuse a token if the current user has insufficient privileges
I am unable to understand this. Can someone shed some light on impersonation. Does it apply to my scenario.

Comment: Negotiate comes from IIS Windows authentication settings and the WCF exception is quite common if you use your fingers to search.

Comment: @Lex Li: thanks for using your fingers